# How to redirect from controller using RedirectToAction method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to redirect from controller action to another controller action like below:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult RedirectToRegister()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Register");
    }

}

public class RegisterController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

I have Url in my cshtml page like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl = '@Url.Action("RedirectToRegister", "Login")';
</script>
```

and I am calling from js like below:

```
function CallRedirectToRegister() {
    window.location = LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl;
}
```

But it is not redirecting me to Register Page. 
My routing is like below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to STAY ON THE SAME PAGE. It will never redirect to another view. If you want to redirect, do a normal submit.

Answer (score 0):

The server-side redirection looks fine, but your client-side call not so much: `$.post(LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl);` starts an AJAX call to the URL. It does not change the current page. For that use this:

```
function CallRedirectToRegister() {
    window.location = LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl;
}
```

This will issue an HTTP GET request. You need to remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from your action for this to work. If you can't do that you have to put a HTML form on your page and submit that to get a POST request. Something like this:

```
function CallRedirectToRegister() {
    $('<form id="redirectForm">').attr('method', 'post').attr('action', LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl).appendTo($('body')).submit();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. And I need to do the redirection from Controller itself rather than doing it from client side javascript. I want to use javascript only to call the controller action which will redirect. Could you please suggest a way to do that?

Comment: Updated the answer to account for the difference between GET and POST requests.

Comment: I tried after removing Post and it looks something like below now:
function CallRedirectToRegister() {
    window.location = LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl;
}

     public ActionResult RedirectToRegister()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Register");
        }



But still it does not redirect. :(

Comment: @AshutoshPandey You should update your question with what you changed and what happened.  Putting code in comments is not ideal unless it is a line or less.

Comment: I have updated the question with the changes I have made. Still it does not redirect me.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call does not redirect to the page. Instead ajax call, use

```
window.location = LoginRedirectToRegisterUrl;
```

And it is not possible to redirect to POST method, because HTTP doesn't support redirection to a page using POST.

Comment: I tried with this change but it did not help. It still does not redirect. I have updated more details in comment section of first answer.